# Why is class file not generated in JavaCompile task in gradle

Tags: java, android, build, compilation, gradle

I met a problem when I use gradle to build my android project. In my build process,I need to compile a single java file to the class file.My project file structure is app -> build_tools->A.java. And my task of compiling A.java is following:

```
 task compileEncodeUtil(type:JavaCompile) {
   println('****************************compileEncodeUtil start*******************')
   source = ['build_tools']
   include '*.java'
   classpath = files('.')
   destinationDir=['build_tools']

 }
```

When I run this task , it runs successfully, but in the folder build_tools, there are no class files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For the following folder structure:

- build.gradle
- build-tools/

  - Lol.java
  - pkg/

    - Lol2.java

the following script works perfectly fine:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task compileEncodeUtil(type:JavaCompile) {
   source = ['build_tools']
   include '**/*.java'
   classpath = files('.')
   destinationDir=['build_tools']
}
```